# Traductions vers l'anglais de phrases idiomatiques françaises

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

> **Demandes de traduction**. Les demandes de traduction en tant que telles ne sont pas admises. Les questions telles que « comment
>   exprimer idiomatiquement [telle idée] en français » ou les demandes
>   d'explication d'une phrase en français sont bienvenues, mais les
>   questions demandant une expertise certaine dans une langue étrangère
>   sont hors sujet.

Je cherche à traduire une phrase idiomatique du français vers l'anglais. Cela demande une bonne compréhension du français (le côté "feeling") que j'ai peur de ne pas retrouver sur SE English Language Learners. En gros il faut être français pour comprendre la nuance.

Je voulais juste confirmer que ce genre de traduction (qui demande bien "*une expertise certaine dans une langue étrangère*", mais aussi une expertise en français pour comprendre le sens) était bien hors sujet.

Answer (score 3):

Si la question porte sur la compréhension du français, elle est bienvenue sur ce site. Par contre, si le problème est la recherche d'une formulation idiomatique dans une langue étrangère, elle est hors sujet. C'est une question d'expertise : ce site concentre des experts en langue française, pas des experts en langue anglaise.

L'anglais est suffisamment répandu sur ce site pour que l'on puisse poser des questions en anglais et y répondre en anglais. Mais expliquer quelque chose ou comprendre une explication demande beaucoup moins d'expertise que trouver la formulation la plus juste.

Il vaudrait mieux poster la question sur [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), en expliquant précisément le sens et les connotations de la phrase originale. Bien sûr il faut mentionner l'original français, mais on ne peut pas s'attendre à ce que tous les gens qui répondraient potentiellement à la question le comprennent. De plus, il faut préciser le contexte, car il n'y a pas forcément une traduction unique qui convient dans tous les contextes.

Here are a few examples of well-received translation requests on ELU:

- [English equivalent of “amae” (甘え) - the feeling of pleasurable dependence on another person](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/236808)
- [English equivalent to the Japanese saying “高転びに転ぶ” - A haughty man should tumble down?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/262214)
- [What is the English equivalent to the Japanese word 学者バカ, “Scholar’s fool”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/108199)
- [What could be a translation of classic-style French titles, such as “Du contrat social”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/377500)
- [What's the English equivalent for the French expression “veille technologique”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/102963)
- [What could be a snappy equivalent for the French catchphrase “si c'est gratuit vous êtes le produit”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/324219)

Comment: Le probléme c'est que ce site (SE) n'est pas adapté à la traduction. Que ce soit sur ELL ou ici, ou mêmes les autres "sous"-sites óù je participe (portuguais et espagnole), les histoires de traduction finissent toujours par causer une certaine ncompréhension....mais enfin, on n'est pas lá pour ça, n'est-ce pas? Je pense que SE pourrait les créer mais ne souhaite pas s'y aventurer....